How to add a checkbox in the uninstaller (maintanence tool) of the Qt installer framework
I'm trying to add a checkbox into my uninstaller. I tried to add it at the installer too and it worked.
I'm creating a .ui, adding it to my meta folder and adding it to the .xml. Then, I'm adding this to the ReadyForInstallation page of the uninstaller, but it doesn't work.
<UserInterfaces>
    <UserInterface>deleteuserfilescheckbox.ui</UserInterface>
</UserInterfaces>

if(installer.isUninstaller())
{
    installer.addWizardPageItem(component, "DeleteUserFilesCheckBox", QInstaller.ReadyForInstallation);
}

